# Order of printing elements of hashset

Tags: java, collections, set

During preparation for Java exam, I encountered this problem:

```
public static Function<String, String> change = i -> {
        if (i.equals("Au"))
            return "Ne";
        else
            return i;
    };

Set<String> someStrings = Set.of("Au", "Ja", "Ta", "Cy", "Cu");
        someStrings = someStrings
                .stream()
                .map(change)
                .map(n -> n.substring(0, 1))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        for (String s : someStrings) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
```

Answers to this question suggest that order of printing is important. But how one should determine order of printing in this case?
My only guess it is reversed order of listing elements in Set.of() method.

Comment: a `HashSet` has no deterministic ordering of its elements

Comment: @Lino: that is true, but not that not a single `HashSet` is (overtly) involved in this code. But the same statement is still true about the `Set` interface itselt: `Set` provides no defined ordering.

Comment: The documentation for [`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) says *There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned*. Only a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) can have a defined ordering of its elements. Since we don't know if it's a TreeSet, there's no guarantee the elements are ordered.

Comment: @JoachimSauer IIRC the implementation of `Collectors.toSet()` uses a `HashSet`, but I still agree with your points

Comment: @Lino: **one** implementation might (or even most/all), but it's explicitly specified that it makes no guarantee about the type of the returned set.

Comment: As everyone pointed already HashSet does not guarantee any insertion order but we can use TreeSet which does , in context of streams this can be achieved in this way  `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));`

Comment: @MisaD.: `TreeSet` isn't ordered, it's sorted: it doesn't maintain insertion order, it maintains "natural order". `LinkedHashSet` maintains insertion order.

Comment: @JoachimSauer indeed you are right then he should use LinkedHashSet ty for pointing to my mistake.

Comment: Seems to be the same exam, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67160632/2711488), we had only three days ago. Perhaps, there are even more questions caused by this horrible exam.

Answer (score 1):

[`Set` in general](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#iterator()) provides no defined order for its iterators:

> The elements are returned in no particular order [...].

`Set.of` is explicitly specified to return [an unordered `Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable):

> - The iteration order of set elements is unspecified and is subject to change.

[`Collectors.toSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()) is defined to construct an unspecified `Set`, which means the general rules of `Set` apply (see above).

There is nothing in the documentation that defines **any** kind of reliable order in here. Any order that an implementation ends up returning here is valid.